# Include css content in php function

Tags: php, css, function, email, send

I need to send emails to users with CSS style, however when the function is called, only the email text is rendered (see the code below)

```
public function render(){ 
   $txt = $this->getText(); 
   //I need another echo $variable to call the css and store the css style content
   //Render the text to be sent to user email
   echo $text; 
   die();
}
```

Basically, the email looks like this:
[image: Email with CSS]

When it goes to the render function, looks like this:

[image: Email without CSS]

So basibally I need to include the CSS in my php function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add html tags to the body of the message. Then you can put inline css to it.
Example:

```
<p style="background-color:#DDD;"> MESSAGE BODY </p>
```